# Selenium Timeout issue when calling

Tags: vba, selenium, google-chrome, ms-access, firefox

Running this code in Access VBA:

```
Private Sub cmd_OpenFirefox_Click()

Dim driver as New FirefoxDriver
driver.Get "http://www.google.com"

End Sub
```

Will open a new Firefox window, but it remains completely blank. And VBA will display error code "21" with this comment: 
"TimeoutError"
"Firefox failed to open the listening port 127.0.0.1:51724 within 15s"

I have installed SELENIUM BASIC version 2.0.9.0, and I'm trying to open a site using Chrome, Firefox or Edge, from code in ACCESS 2016 VBA. I've already checked "Selenium Type Library" in Tools-> References.

The same happens with Chrome and Edge.

Browsers versions:

Google Chrome: Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Microsoft Edge: Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 / Microsoft EdgeHTML 15.15063

Mozilla Firefox: Firefox 55.0.3 (32-bit)

What's wrong?

Comment: If you're asking for a software recommendation, see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/. Else: provide a detailed description of what you tried, and any errors that follow, so we can help you solve the issue.

Comment: You might want to re-ask this question with a title like "Selenium TimeourError when calling from Access VBA". I can't cast reopen votes, but I'm all for answering this question, and since it's quite different from when you first asked it, re-asking it will be appropriate. But let's leave the autofilling out of it, and just try to fix the timeout. Have you disabled the Windows Firewall to see if that makes a difference?

Comment: Dear Erik, thank you very much for your help. I haven't tried that yet. I am following your advises as well as I can. Apologies for my mistakes, I am not used to ask in forums, this is the second time I make a question in a forum, and the first here. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: Glad to help, always good to have new members. You will notice StackOverflow is a lot different from other fora, in the sense that it's really about coding questions, which should be as small, clear and simple as possible, and answers, which should be the same, and that for both questions and answers, some effort and research is expected. So no conversations (except in the comments) or anything like that. The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a good place to get acquainted with the site.

Answer (score 0):

After verifying that .net was installed and I had it working. There appears to be an issue with the .quit function that was completed the last run that was completed.  Wiating usually solves the problem. I was able to solve this with the following code:


**Dim y As Integer**

y = 0

StartNewChrome:
y = y + 1
If y > 5 Then MsgBox "Tried 5 Times in ChromeDriver"
On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo 0
On Error GoTo StartNewChrome
Set objIE = New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
objIE.Start "chrome"
On Error GoTo 0

for you it would be this code:

**Dim y As Integer**

y = 0

StartNewChrome:
y = y + 1
If y > 5 Then MsgBox "Tried 5 Times in ChromeDriver"
On Error GoTo -1
On Error GoTo 0
On Error GoTo StartNewChrome
Set objIE = New Selenium.FirefoxDriver
objIE.Start "firefox"
On Error GoTo 0

Comment: Please use code formatting for code.